# DataSpell not working with conda/miniforge

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, dataspell

I have an env, and I have a py script to check if everything works fine:

```
import sys
import tensorflow.keras
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
import tensorflow as tf
print(f"Tensor Flow Version: {tf.__version__}")
print(f"Keras Version: {tensorflow.keras.__version__}")
print()
print(f"Python {sys.version}")
print(f"Pandas {pd.__version__}")
print(f"Scikit-Learn {sk.__version__}")
gpu = len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))>0
print("GPU is", "available" if gpu else "NOT AVAILABLE")
```

[image]

this is the output from the jupyter notebook... now, I would like to have a better IDE, in particular DataSpell, however, even though I've configured the correct interpreter:[image]

It does not work:
[image]

the error message:

> Jupyter server process exited with code 1 /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml-apple-metal/bin/python: No module named jupyter

any idea?

If you need other informations, please just ask, I'll post everything you need...